# A depth (z-index) nightmare

Tags: css, z-index

[The best way to illustrate this question is with...a Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/jcoc611/pftPS/2/) **Before** you visit the fiddle, notice there is text behind the grayest element, which is on top of a light gray element that has a border.

There is a main wrapping div (*root*), and two wrapping divs inside (*wrap1* and *wrap2*). The problem here is that I need the content of *wrap2* (*highlight*) to be behind the content of *wrap1* (*text*), but in front of the background of the *root*.

This, however, must **not** change:

- The HTML, the elements and wraps should be left untouched. Excluding the order of *wrap1* and *wrap2* inside *root*.
- The *highlight* div must keep the absolute positioning.
- Styling *highlight* with `background-color` is not an option, the existence of *highlight* is a must.

PS: the *italics* reference the id's of `<div>`s in the fiddle example, for whomever was too lazy to visit it.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to make a fiddle :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to display the text in front of the highlight by [adding a `z-index` to *text*](http://jsfiddle.net/pftPS/6/).  (Adding the `z-index` to *wrap1* also works.)  The trick is to remember that `z-index` doesn't apply to statically-positioned elements, so you need to give the same div `position: relative`.

```
#text {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

(Large `z-index` because I've been bitten by IE not respecting low values in the past.  May or may not still be an issue.  ;-)

Comment: +1 Thanks, I'll accept it asap. I actually tried the `z-index` in both wraps and it didn't work, but this does!

Comment: But wait, just like a challenge, can you do it without `position:relative`?

Comment: @JCOC — Glad to hear you got it working!  [I was able to get it working on *wrap1*](http://jsfiddle.net/pftPS/17/) with the same styles; you may not have had `position` set.  :-)

Comment: Yes, exactly, I never set any position to anything...good tips! PS: it's JCOC lol

Comment: @JCOC — I'm 99% sure this can't be done without `z-index`, which in turn can't be used without setting `position` to something other than `static`.  But using `relative` shouldn't cause you any problems unless there is absolutely-positioned content inside *text*.

Comment: @JCOC — I don't know what you're talking about!  I've gotten your name right every time, see?  ;-)

Comment: I absolutely love to edit my posts when I mess up haha! Well, about the position thing, yea I guess I can live with it!

Answer (score 0):

```
#wrap1{position:absolute;z-index:2;}
```

Comment: I prefar the other guys answer.

Answer (score 0):

z-index can be difficult to grasp. I think somebody already answered your question, but if you want to learn more how they work, this is a pretty comprehensive guide:

http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/05/29/an-indepth-coverage-on-css-layers-z-index-relative-and-absolute-positioning/

And also, here is a link where you can try out different z-index and how they are affected by different position properties (the main reason for difficulty)

http://tjkdesign.com/articles/z-index/teach_yourself_how_elements_stack.asp